# LinQ Query not working properly when written without splitting the queries

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a linQ query which does not fetch data when written as follows.

```
if (this.locationRepository.GetAvailableLocations(accountId)
      .All(x => x.Orders.Any(y => y.OrderSubtypeId == int)OrderSubtype.Values.MigrationAdd)))
            {
                      //Logic Implementation
            }
```

But when same query is splitt into 2 queries and assigned to different variables, it returns true condition as follows.

```
     var availableLocationsOrders = this.locationRepository.GetAvailableLocations(accountId).SelectMany(x => x.Orders);
     var addMigrationOrders = availableLocationsOrders.Where(x => x.OrderSubtypeId == (int)OrderSubtype.Values.MigrationAdd);

if(addMigrationOrders.Any()){
        //Control enters inside as the if condition returns records
}
```

Can anyone let me know why the first query does not yield any result?

Comment: Why do you think your two queries are equivalent ? There is nothing corresponding to the "All" in you second alternative. And All is a pretty exclusive predicate.
In the second one, you select all with Subtype=MigrationAdd, in the first one, you select all that consist only of Subtype=MigrationAdd and nothing else.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by this statement.. " In the second one, you select all with Subtype=MigrationAdd, in the first one, you select all that consist only of Subtype=MigrationAdd" Both look same for me.

Comment: The first has nothing with "SelectMany" and "Where", The second has nothing with "All "and "Any". No idea why you say they look the same, they don't even look similiar.
Splitting a query means, to put a Semicolon in a place there a point is. Nothing else.
There is nothing replacing the "All" or the "Any" in your second version. It's completly different.